# tkinter error: partially initialized module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Tk'

Tags: python, tkinter, vscode

Tengo un problema, estoy usando VS Code y cuando intento correr mi codigo me aparece partially initialized module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Tk' (most likely due to a circular import)

ya cheque que no hubiera errores en el codigo y es imposible ya que ese mismo codigo corre en el IDLE de python asi que no es un problema de codigo, creo yo que es algun problema de VS Code pero nose como solucionarlo ya intente de todo y por cierto ayer me corria ese codigo y hoy fue cuando de repente ya no funciona. este es mi codigo:
[image: como pueden ver el codigo esta correcto y abajo en la terminal aparece el error del que hablo]

```
import tkinter as tk

class Aplicacion:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ventana1=tk.Tk()
        self.ventana1.title("Prueba")
        self.boton1=tk.Button(self.ventana1, text="Varón", command=self.presionvaron)
        self.boton1.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.boton2=tk.Button(self.ventana1, text="Mujer", command=self.presionmujer)
        self.boton2.grid(column=1, row=0)
        self.ventana1.mainloop()

    def presionvaron(self):
        self.ventana1.title('Varón')

    def presionmujer(self):
        self.ventana1.title('Mujer')


aplicacion1=Aplicacion()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Aplicacion:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.wind = window
    
        self.boton1= tk.Button(self.wind, text="Varón", command=self.presionvaron)
        self.boton1.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.boton2= tk.Button(self.wind, text="Mujer", command=self.presionmujer)
        self.boton2.grid(column=1, row=0)

    def presionvaron(self):
        self.wind.title('Varón')

    def presionmujer(self):
        self.wind.title('Mujer')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Tk()
    application = Aplicacion(window)
    window.title("prueba")
    window.mainloop()
```

Siempre intenta asignar tu frame general fuera de la clase para que puedas tener un control mejor de esta, ya que si lo declaras dentro, puedes tener problemas

Lo que hice fue que fuera de tu clase Aplicacion, asigne Tkinter y a este mismo lo mande a la clase, dentro de tu funcion de inicio, asignas a un objeto (POO) y con esto empiezas a trabajar correctamente.